# Unable to ssh into same machine unless manually adding `.local` to the hostname

Tags: ssh, dns

I am using a clustering tool (hadoop) running locally that must be able to do passwordless ssh as follows:

```
 ssh $(hostname)
```

On my mac laptop this does not work. Here are pertinent entries in the `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost 
xx.xx.242.47    TCA0080ALKVTAGB
```

It is possible to `ping` the hostname:

```
ping $(hostname)
PING TCA0080ALKVTAGB.local (xx.xx.242.47): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from xx.xx.242.47: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
64 bytes from xx.xx.242.47: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.115 ms
```

However trying to `ssh` to the hostname does not work:

```
 $ssh $(hostname)
ssh: Could not resolve hostname tca0080alkvtagb: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

By adding the `.local` even `.ssh` works

```
 ssh $(hostname).local   # this works
```

Note: I had already added `.local` to the global search domains (via `System Preferences | Network | Advanced | DNS` ):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the corporate firewall is messing with the DNS (yes - even for the resolution of the local machine..) . I do not know the details but when the firewall is disabled the DNS is working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) in your `$(hostname)`

So you need to make your /etc/hosts like:

> 127.0.0.1   localhost
>
> xx.xx.242.47    TCA0080ALKVTAGB TCA0080ALKVTAGB.local

Comment: Nice idea - I had actually already tried that. Turns out to be a weird firewall issue.  But I'll give you an upvote anyways.